# Spring MVC @PathVariable getting truncated

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, get

I have a controller that provides RESTful access to information:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = Routes.BLAH_GET + "/{blahName}")
public ModelAndView getBlah(@PathVariable String blahName, HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response) {
```

The problem I am experiencing is that if I hit the server with a path variable with special characters it gets truncated. For example:
http://localhost:8080/blah-server/blah/get/blah2010.08.19-02:25:47

The parameter blahName will be blah2010.08

However, the call to request.getRequestURI() contains all the information passed in.

Any idea how to prevent Spring from truncating the @PathVariable?

Comment: It seems this has been solved in Spring 3.2-M2: see [Allow valid file extension paths for content negotiation to be specified](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7632) and [its documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-content-negotiation).

Answer (score 153):

Try a regular expression for the `@RequestMapping` argument:

```
RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = Routes.BLAH_GET + "/{blahName:.+}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this helped me solve a case where usernames got trimmed somehow .. (-: 
The other option with 'useDefaultSuffixPattern' was not an option because we're using @Configuration spring classes instead of XML.

Comment: This works, but what is the significance of the colon in the regex?

Comment: Noah, I haven't used this in a long time, but I think the colon separates the regular expression from the argument name to bind it to.

Comment: we had a similar problam /item/user@abc.com, anything after @ was truncated, this was solved by adding another slash /item/user@abc.com/

Answer (score 61):

This is probably closely related to [SPR-6164](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6164). Briefly, the framework tries to apply some smarts to the URI interpretation, removing what it thinks are file extensions. This would have the effect of turning `blah2010.08.19-02:25:47` into `blah2010.08`, since it thinks the `.19-02:25:47` is a file extension.

As described in the linked issue, you can disable this behaviour by declaring your own `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` bean in the app context, and setting its `useDefaultSuffixPattern` property to `false`. This will override the default behaviour, and stop it molesting your data.

Comment: Turning extension based content negotiation on by default seems like such a strange choice.  How many systems really expose the same resource in different formats in practice?

Comment: I tried this the morning and still had truncated path variables.

Comment: +1 for a great answer and also for using the phrase "molesting your data"

Comment: this might not be a good solution if you use a .xml/.json suffix on pages and the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver

Comment: For Spring 3.1 users - if you're using the new `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` instead, the property to set is `useSuffixPatternMatch` (also to `false`).
@Ted: the linked issue mentions that in 3.2 they hope to add a bit more control so it doesn't have to be all-or-nothing.

Comment: In Spring 4.2 this is slightly easier to configure.  We use Java config classes and extend the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` which provides a simple hook:`public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer)` - just override that and set up the path matching how you like.

Answer (score 34):

Spring considers that anything behind the last dot is a file extension such as `.json`or `.xml` and truncate it to retrieve your parameter.

So if you have `/{blahName}`:

- `/param`, `/param.json`, `/param.xml` or `/param.anything` will result in a param with value `param`
- `/param.value.json`, `/param.value.xml` or `/param.value.anything` will result in a param with value `param.value`

If you change your mapping to `/{blahName:.+}` as suggested, any dot, including the last one, will be considered as part of your parameter:

- `/param` will result in a param with value `param`
- `/param.json` will result in a param with value `param.json`
- `/param.xml` will result in a param with value `param.xml`
- `/param.anything` will result in a param with value `param.anything`
- `/param.value.json` will result in a param with value `param.value.json`
- ...

If you don't care of extension recognition, you can disable it by overriding `mvc:annotation-driven` automagic:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="contentNegotiationManager"/>
    <property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

So, again, if you have `/{blahName}`:

- `/param`, `/param.json`, `/param.xml` or `/param.anything` will result in a param with value `param`
- `/param.value.json`, `/param.value.xml` or `/param.value.anything` will result in a param with value `param.value`

Note: the difference from the default config is visible only if you have a mapping like `/something.{blahName}`. See [Resthub project issue](https://github.com/resthub/resthub-spring-stack/issues/217).

If you want to keep extension management, since Spring 3.2 you can also set the useRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch property of RequestMappingHandlerMapping bean in order to keep suffixPattern recognition activated but limited to registered extension.

Here you define only json and xml extensions:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="contentNegotiationManager"/>
    <property name="useRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false"/>
    <property name="favorParameter" value="true"/>
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <value>
            json=application/json
            xml=application/xml
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note that mvc:annotation-driven accepts now a contentNegotiation option to provide a custom bean but the property of RequestMappingHandlerMapping has to be changed to true (default false) (cf. https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7632).

For that reason, you still have to override all the mvc:annotation-driven configuration. I opened a ticket to Spring to ask for a custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11253. Please vote if you are interested in.

While overriding, be careful to consider also custom Execution management overriding. Otherwise, all your custom Exception mappings will fail. You will have to reuse messageCoverters with a list bean:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />

<util:list id="messageConverters">
    <bean class="your.custom.message.converter.IfAny"></bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
</util:list>

<bean name="exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver">
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
    <property name="messageConverters" ref="messageConverters"/>
</bean>

<bean name="handlerAdapter"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService" />
            <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters" ref="messageConverters"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
</bean>
```

I implemented, in the open source project [Resthub](http://resthub.github.io/) that I am part of, a set of tests on these subjects: see https://github.com/resthub/resthub-spring-stack/pull/219/files and https://github.com/resthub/resthub-spring-stack/issues/217

Answer (score 17):

Everything after the last dot is interpreted as file extension and cut off by default.
In your spring config xml you can add `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and set `useDefaultSuffixPattern` to `false` (default is `true`).

So open your spring xml `mvc-config.xml` (or however it is called) and add

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Now your `@PathVariable` `blahName` (and all other, too) should contain the full name including all dots.

EDIT: Here is a [link to the spring api](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html)

Comment: I have not tried, but [others claim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135329/how-to-change-spring-mvcs-behavior-in-handling-url-dot-character/11141184#11141184) you'd then also need to remove `<mvc:annotation-driven />` if applicable.

Answer (score 9):

Using the correct Java configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer)
    {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer)
    {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me. Running on Tomcat Spring version 4.3.14

Answer (score 8):

I also ran into the same issue, and setting the property to false didn't help me either. However, [the API says](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html#setUseDefaultSuffixPattern%28boolean%29):

> Note that paths which include a ".xxx" suffix or end with "/" already
>   will not be transformed using the default suffix pattern in any case.

I tried adding "/end" to my RESTful URL, and the problem went away. I'm not please with the solution, but it did work.

BTW, I don't know what the Spring designers were thinking when they added this "feature" and then turned it on by default. IMHO, it should be removed.

Comment: I agree. I was recently bit by this.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved by this hack

1) Added HttpServletRequest  in @PathVariable like below

```
 @PathVariable("requestParam") String requestParam, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
```

2) Get the URL directly (At this level no truncation) in the request

```
request.getPathInfo()
```

[Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Answer (score 4):

adding the ":.+" worked for me, but not until I removed outer curly brackets.

`value = {"/username/{id:.+}"}` didn't work

`value = "/username/{id:.+}"`   works

Hope I helped someone :]

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this and the solutions here didn't generally work as I expected.

I suggest using a SpEL expression and multiple mappings, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, 
    value = {Routes.BLAH_GET + "/{blahName:.+}", 
             Routes.BLAH_GET + "/{blahName}/"})
```

Answer (score 3):

The file extension problem only exists if the parameter is in the last part of the URL. Change

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = Routes.BLAH_GET + "/{blahName}")
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(
   method = RequestMethod.GET, value = Routes.BLAH_GET + "/{blahName}/safe")
```

and all will be well again-

Answer (score 3):

If you can edit the address that requests are sent to, simple fix would be to add a trailing slash to them (and also in the `@RequestMapping` value):

```
/path/{variable}/
```

so the mapping would look like:

```
RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = Routes.BLAH_GET + "/{blahName}/")
```

See also [Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18378817/1995170).

Answer (score 3):

```
//in your xml dispatcher  add this property to your default annotation mapper bean as follow
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you are facing is due to **spring** interpreting the **last** part of the uri **after** the **dot (.)** as a ***file extension*** like .json or .xml . So when spring tries to resolve the path variable it simply truncates the rest of the data after it encounters a dot (.) at the end of the uri.
**Note:** also this happens only if you keep the path variable at the end of the uri.

For example consider uri : https://localhost/example/gallery.df/link.ar

```
@RestController
public class CustomController {
    @GetMapping("/example/{firstValue}/{secondValue}")
    public void example(@PathVariable("firstValue") String firstValue,
      @PathVariable("secondValue") String secondValue) {
        // ...  
    }
}
```

In the above url firstValue = "gallery.df" and secondValue="link" , the last bit after the . gets truncated when the path variable gets interpreted.

So, to prevent this there is two possible ways:

**1.) Using a regexp mapping**

Use a regex at the end part of mapping

```
@GetMapping("/example/{firstValue}/{secondValue:.+}")   
public void example(
  @PathVariable("firstValue") String firstValue,
  @PathVariable("secondValue") String secondValue) {
    //...
}
```

By using + , we indicate any value after the dot will also be part of the path variable.

**2.) Adding a slash at the end of our @PathVariable**

```
@GetMapping("/example/{firstValue}/{secondValue}/")
public void example(
  @PathVariable("firstValue") String firstValue,
  @PathVariable("secondValue") String secondValue) {
    //...
}
```

This will enclose our second variable protecting it from Spring’s default behavior.

**3) By overriding Spring's default webmvc configuration**

Spring provides ways to override the default configurations that gets imported by using the annotations *@EnableWebMvc*.We can customize the Spring MVC configuration by declaring our own ***DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping*** bean in the application context and setting its ***useDefaultSuffixPattern*** property to false.
Example:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping 
      requestMappingHandlerMapping() {

        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping
          = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        return handlerMapping;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that overriding this default configuration, affects all urls.

**Note :** here we are extending the WebMvcConfigurationSupport  class to override the default methods. There is one more way to override the deault configurations by implementing the WebMvcConfigurer interface.
For more details on this read : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html

Answer (score 2):

Java based configuration solution to prevent truncation (using a not-deprecated class):

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

@Configuration
public class PolRepWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        final RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super
                .requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        // disable the truncation after .
        handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        // disable the truncation after ;
        handlerMapping.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        return handlerMapping;
    }
}
```

[Source: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/spring-mvc-customizing-requestmappinghandlermapping.html](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/spring-mvc-customizing-requestmappinghandlermapping.html)

**UPDATE:**

I realized having some problems with Spring Boot auto-configuration when I used the approach above (some auto-configuration doesn't get effective).

Instead, I started to use the `BeanPostProcessor` approach. It seemed to be working better.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(MyBeanPostProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerMapping) {
            setRemoveSemicolonContent((RequestMappingHandlerMapping) bean,
                    beanName);
            setUseSuffixPatternMatch((RequestMappingHandlerMapping) bean,
                    beanName);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    private void setRemoveSemicolonContent(
            RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping,
            String beanName) {
        logger.info(
                "Setting 'RemoveSemicolonContent' on 'RequestMappingHandlerMapping'-bean to false. Bean name: {}",
                beanName);
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
    }

    private void setUseSuffixPatternMatch(
            RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping,
            String beanName) {
        logger.info(
                "Setting 'UseSuffixPatternMatch' on 'RequestMappingHandlerMapping'-bean to false. Bean name: {}",
                beanName);
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
}
```

[Inspired from: http://ronaldxq.blogspot.com/2014/10/spring-mvc-setting-alwaysusefullpath-on.html](http://ronaldxq.blogspot.com/2014/10/spring-mvc-setting-alwaysusefullpath-on.html)

Answer (score 2):

if you are sure that your text will not match any of default extensions you can use below code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My preferable solution to prevent the Spring MVC @PathVariable to get truncated is to add trailing slash at the end of the path variable.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/email/{email}/")
```

So, the request will look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/email/test@test.com/
```