# How to change Spring MVC's behavior in handling url 'dot' character

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to migrate a web project off from Jersey to Spring MVC 3.0. The process was really straightforward up to the moment when I started to migrate the controllers supposed to handle URL's with dot notations: "/myApp/resources/create/**root.subFolder1**". Spring MVC seems to shamelessly cut the **".subFolder1"** part from the URL, which happens deep inside framework code (see **AbstractUrlHandlerMapping** class)

```
uriTemplateVariables.putAll(getPathMatcher().extractUriTemplateVariables(matchingPattern, urlPath));
```

So my controller method gets invoked with **root** path parameter, not **root.subFolder1**

I'd really like to find a way to customize this behavior. Any advices?

PS. The requirement is kinda to keep the existing URL structure, i.e. workarounds like switching to query params "/myApp/resources/create/**?path=root.subFolder1**" I cannot consider.

PS. My Spring config looks like

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="my.app.pkg"/>
```

Comment: Btw, in the future it might be a good idea to include the Java tag, as that might get more visibility.

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility which may be easier in some circumstances is to add a trailing `/` to the end of the URL.

So your URL would be `/myApp/resources/create/root.subFolder1/`

This works in my app using Spring MVC 3.1.

Comment: This was best solution for me. I needed the annotation tags for the rest of the site.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

This should make it so that Spring won't try to parse extensions.

See also: [Spring MVC @PathVariable getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated)

And: [Spring Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html)

Potential config files:

web.xml (where I set the servlet stuff)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/*.xml,classpath*:applicationContext.xml,classpath*:restApplicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And then in WEB/INF/spring/mvc-config.xml I have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: If this helped, accept it. If not, further explain the problem :)

Comment: Should I declare this bean by itself or out is as a dependency to some other bean? Looks like just declaring it in spring servlet xml config doesn't help...

Comment: I'm assuming the servlet.xml config is where you configure the servlet. Do you use any init-param config for contextConfigLocation?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The reason is that this property isn't supposed to address my issue, at least the documentation clearly states that "paths which include a ".xxx" suffix or end with "/" already will not be
  * transformed using the default suffix pattern in any case."

Comment: Addition: when I added DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping to a spring context, and placed two breakpoints in the code: 1) in setUseDefaultSuffixPattern() and 2) in addUrlsForPath(), both of class DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping, it appeared that the addUrls gets invoked BEFORE setUseDefaultSuffixPattern, which might be the part of the reason why I can't override spring behavior

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't work for you. I had the exact same problem you are describing. I feel like though it won't get transformed it's still going to look for a content negotiator of "subFolder1" which it obviously won't find. Maybe you could share the whole of your servlet xml file?

Comment: The weird thing I notice from logs is that actual url mapping happens TWICE: [INFO ][.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/available/{userId}] onto handler 'userConnector'
[INFO ][.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/available/{userId}.*] onto handler 'userConnector'
[INFO ][.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/available/{userId}/] onto handler 'userConnector'

[INFO ][.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/available/{userId}] onto handler 'userConnector'

Comment: Try taking out the mvnc:annotation-driven line and see what happens.

Comment: I'm almost certain either mvc:annotation-driven or context:component-scan is overwriting the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping that you're trying to add in.

Comment: Well, indeed it's the mvc:annotation-driven which causeing the problems. But how to setup annotation support without it?

Comment: Well, here is what it does: http://rapid-web.tumblr.com/post/296916668/what-does-annotation-driven-do

Perhaps from that you can determine what you need to use to make things work. I've never used the annotation-driven config because of these types of problems so I usually set things up just for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

In order for

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

to work you have to remove/comment out the

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

and any other mvc: configurations defined as they override your custom bean declarations.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bitch.  A guy on our team here got it to work over the weekend.  We were going to go with underscore but he got it.  He removed @Controller from the controller class attributes and left @RequestMapping blank for the class.  On the public methods for Http get and put he added "/2.0/" to the @RequestMapping.  Example below.

```
@RequestMapping
public class EndpointController {

@RequestMapping(value="/2.0/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST,
consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<EndpointView> create( @Valid @RequestBody EndpointView endpointParams, HttpServletRequest request )
```

Good luck everyone. This problem sucked.

Answer (score 1):

I did almost the same as Robert Beltran but I left @Controller annotation for the class. Important is to put "/1.0/" to the @RequestMapping on the methods, not in class annotation.
My example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class ClientApi {

private final String API_PREFIX = "/api/1.0/client";

@RequestMapping(value = API_PREFIX + "/{clientId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ClientDetailsImpl get(@PathVariable String clientId) {
    // my code
}
}
```

Comment: I just saw this because we got hit again. Different project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The above answer should correct, but be sure to remove `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` from your XML configuration, otherwise the bean definition is overruled by the one part of the annotation-driven tag.

See the [java docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.html) and the [source code](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.0.4.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java?format=ok) for all the configuration you miss when this convenience tag is removed.