# Binding dot-separated Strings with @PathVariable in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping( value="/servers/{server}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public @ResponseBody List<Application> getServerInformation( String server ) {
    logger.debug( "Request for server: " + server );
    ...
}
```

When I request **/servers/test.myserver.com**, the bound variable has value **test.myserver**. In general, for any request that includes dot-separated values the last part is omitted from the bound variable's value.
I am using Spring 3.0.4

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135329/how-to-change-spring-mvcs-behavior-in-handling-url-dot-character

Answer (score 9):

You can use Ant style matching patterns.  For your example you can simply do this:

```
@RequestMapping( value="/servers/{server:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public @ResponseBody List<Application> getServerInformation(
                          @PathVariable(value = "server") String server ) {
    logger.debug( "Request for server: " + server );
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to change the useDefaultSuffixPattern of DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping. Check [How to change Spring MVC's behavior in handling url 'dot' character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135329/how-to-change-spring-mvcs-behavior-in-handling-url-dot-character) for a discussion on this.