# How to prevent Spring MVC parameter from being truncated after "."

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am working on a web project and using Spring MVC 3.1.1. Spring MVC is used to serve REST services (using URL annotations)

Regarding to my problem:

Let's say my url path for a service is as;

```
http://localhost:8080/MyAppName/services/meteo/queryWeatherData/lon/39.1123/lat/39.3123
```

And my controller method is as;

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = {"/queryWeatherData/lon/{lon}/lat/{lat}"})
    public void queryWeatherData(
            final @PathVariable("lon") float lon,
            final @PathVariable("lat") float lat,
            final HttpServletResponse response, final HttpServletRequest request) {
//
// DO STUFF and prepare response
//
}
```

I see that the second parameter (lat) is truncated after "." so I see that the value is 39.0 in server side.

I tried declaring a DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping bean in my app-context.xml and set its useDefaultSuffixPattern to false but it did not work.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try putting a slash at the end i.e. `http://localhost:8080/MyAppName/services/meteo/queryWeatherData/lon/39.1123/lat/39.3123/`. If that changes it it maybe that it looks as `.3123` as file extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated

Comment: I am aware of the possible duplicate issue but the instructions on that one did not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` bean with `useDefaultSuffixPattern=false` is the right approach, but make sure you also comment out:

`<mvc:annotation-driven />`

See: [How to change Spring MVC's behavior in handling url 'dot' character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135329/how-to-change-spring-mvcs-behavior-in-handling-url-dot-character/11141184#11141184)

Comment: I tried declaring the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` bean with `useDefaultSuffixPattern=false` but I didn't comment out `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and that was the case. Thank you very much