# Spring MVC is dropping a @PathVariable

Tags: spring-mvc

If I hit the controller multiple times and hammer it, occasionally my modelCode parameter comes through as null.  However the URL has the modelCode in it.
Using Spring Framework 3.0.5.RELEASE

```
 @RequestMapping(value="ws/getallvariants/{channelCode}/{modelCode}/{regionId}/{year}")
    public ModelAndView getAllVariants(@PathVariable("channelCode") String channelCode, 
          @PathVariable("modelCode") String modelCode,@PathVariable("regionId") String regionId,@PathVariable("year") String year){
```

`if (modelCode == null)
    {
        int i = 0; // this should never hit, but does.
    }`

Comment: Have you checked the scope for that controller (is it the default singleton)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the spring framework again to the latest version appears to have worked.  Apparently when we updated our framework something didn't work correctly.

EDIT:

So this wasn't our issue at all...  We had implemented a String Trimmer Editor incorrectly and it was keeping state.  So when we put the call under load it would cross results.

Comment: And a year later the issue re-appears.  It appears that it wasn't solved in the first place.

Comment: The issue was a stringTrimmerEditor actually that wasn't implemented correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, RegEx was the most reliable for me as well.  Did this to grab an email address as a  parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "rest/userreadserv/search/{email:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getUserAccountByEmail(@PathVariable String email) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Spring MVC @PathVariable getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated) . The regex approach worked for me:

`@RequestMapping({ "/servers/{serverName:.+}" })`

Comment: In this case not the issue.  The parameter is 2 or three alpha numeric characters, no decimals.  I've also seen the regionId now go null.

Answer (score 0):

```
//in your xml dispatcher  add this property to your default annotation mapper bean as follow
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```