# Spring Boot + Angular2 on same server

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot

I'm successfully integrated my Angular2 application with Spring Boot backend following [this tutorial](https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/12/angular2-spring-boot-getting-started/), placing the compiled JS resources to a /ui subdirectory. Everything works fine basically, the Angular2 application is accessible through the *appname/ui* URL.

However, I'd like to know if there is a way to tell Spring to 'pass-through' URLs that children of the */ui* path, as currently Spring intercepts every requests targeting */ui/**, preventing the Angular2 Router properly navigating to resources under the */ui* path.

Currently, I only have this mapping in one of my controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ui")
public String uiIndex() {
    return "/ui/index.html";
}
```

With this, the interface properly shows up at */ui*, but Spring sends me errors and 404s for everything under it, **when I address them directly from browser**. Router navigation inside the Angular2 app works perfectly though.

**EDIT**

I'm adding the compiled Angular2 resources from target/ui to static/ui folder with this config (my project uses maven build):

```
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
                <include>templates/*.*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>target/ui</directory>
            <targetPath>static/ui</targetPath>
        </resource>
```

As to be clear, the only problem is, when I enter an URL in the browser like */ui/home/settings*, Spring intercepts the request and throws errors. I can happily navigate to /ui, and then to /home/settings in the Angular context though.

Comment: The standard location for static resources in a Spring boot app is under src/main/resources/static. Just put your Angular resources there, and Spring Boot will serve them.

Comment: You may want a mapping that ends with `/**`.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/modular/README.adoc?

Comment: Also maybe  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769200/configure-spring-boot-for-spa-frontend

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes, I think I need something like this, but it also seems a problem that my Angular resources don't reside under static/ but rather in static/ui. I tried using `@RequestMapping(value = "/{path:[^\\.]*}")` adding the _ui/_ fragment, but it does not seem to work. I'm still trying though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial-and-error, I was finally manage to do what I wanted. Many thanks to *@EpicPandaforce* 's [useful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246710/spring-boot-angular2-on-same-server?noredirect=1#comment75502546_44246710) and [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516667/springboot-angular2-how-to-handle-html5-urls)

The final solution was to create a `@RequestMapping` in a `@Controller` like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ui/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirectUi() {
    return "forward:/ui/index.html";
}
```

Comment: I think you have an extra '[' before the 'path:' bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ResourceHandlers to configure static content serving in spring boot.

Example

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/ui").addResourceLocations("file:/path/to/your/angular/files");
    }
}
```

See https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Now, Step 5 of the tutorial you mentioned has a cleaner way of doing this, did you skip that step? (src/main/resources/static)

Comment: Please see my edited question, I hope it's a bit clearer now, what my real problem is. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most simple way to do what you want is using Angular Hash Location Strategy.

`import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';`

`{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }`

I hope to help.