# Angular RouterModule in Java WAR

Tags: java, angular, routes, war, angular-routing

I use Angular's Routing functionality in my Angular 6.0.5 app. Hence, I have paths in my app like:

- `http://localhost:8080/area`
- `http://localhost:8080/barn`
- `http://localhost:8080/tower`

Running my app using `ng serve` works well. I can directly type an address like `http://localhost:8080/barn` into the browser and it will load the app and go to the appropriate place within the app.

After building the app I copy the entire content of `/dist/` into a Java WebApplication, that results in a WAR after compilation.

To build it I use `ng build --prod --build-optimizer --base-href=/myappdir/`

When I run the WAR in an application server like Wildfly I can successfully go the the URL `http://localhost:8080/myappdir/` and load the app. Clicking some routing button within the app also successfully changes the URL to i.e. `http://localhost:8080/barn`, but if I type the URL `http://localhost:8080/barn` into the browser myself and then hit enter, I get an error, that the page could not be loaded.

If I run an Angular app which makes use of Angular's routing functionality on a web server like Nginx, I have to tell the web server to point to the `index.html` file even if the URL requests a different file. So with Nginx this would be [done with configuration](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-404-error-with-existing-urls-angular-2-one-page-application-with-routing) like this: `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`. So I guess the problem is the same within the WAR file.

What must I configure within the WAR file to have it point to the `index.html` file?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39337121/5695162

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40769350/5695162

Comment: @Vikas Thanks for the three links. The first one I already know, but there I have to make settings to the server directly, and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @Vikas I'd also love to use `@Controller`, but I don't use Spring. I just created a plain and simple Java Web App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it out myself. So, in case someone is trying the same as I do, here is the description to solve this matter without making tweaks within the web server.

Add a 404 error page to the `web.xml` inside of the Java project. The following four lines will do the trick:

```
<web-app ...>

    ...

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hashes for the routes. This way, you won't break it. In your app.module.ts:

```
RouterModule.forRoot( yourAppRoutes, { useHash: true });
```