# How to integrate angular6 + spring boot in tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, angular6

I want to integrate  angular 6 and spring boot application and final output make executable jar.I referred some tutorial and followed below steps .

1) Using ng build --prod i build angular project.

2) Created static folder under resource folder in spring boot and Copied dist folder to static folder .

3) Build the jar using maven and deployed in tomcat .But i am always getting 404 when i am trying to access index.html

My spring boot directory looks like below:

[spring boot directory and index.html image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmjGr.png)

Can i need to change base href url in index.html ?
Please suggest me .

Comment: have you registered the resourceLocations ? Also please post what you've tried so far

Comment: Hit http://localhost:8080/my-test/index.html in browser

Comment: The content of my-test must be directly under /static. I.e. you must not have that my-test directory under static. You need the files directly.

Comment: Why do you want to deploy them together, I think it's not a good idea also "routing" will be an issue for you. In my opinion you should deploy them separate. Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769200/configure-spring-boot-for-spa-frontend

Comment: @MuhammedOzdogan It's a perfectly valid option. Spring Boot is perfectly able to serve static resources, and is perfectly able to deal with Angular routing with a simple filter. It's quite a classical combo. All this build of the jar file should be automated by Maven, though.

Comment: @MuhammedOzdogan i need to pack a  single jar that is my requirement

Comment: @JBNizet i tried under static folder that is not helping always i am getting 404

Comment: @gvsk225 Could you try another html file that isn't an Angular index.html file under the static folder.