# Spring Boot 2.6 and Angular in static Resources

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769200/configure-spring-boot-for-spa-frontend) question that has already been asked and answered but is not 100% up-to-date.

We used the solution from Chris Gaskill for quite some time and it suited us perfectly because we wanted to redirect requests that contain more than one path segment (i.e. `/foo/bar`)

From Spring Boot 2.4 on, Boot uses the `PathPatternParser` instead of the `AntPathMatcher`, wherein the former does not support `**` at the start of a pattern anymore ([see docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)).

Is there some other solution to get the same behavior? What do you use to redirect all requests, that did not match anything else, to the `index.html` of the Angular app?

This is the code of the controller that forwards the requests.

```
@Controller
class SpaRoutingController {

  @GetMapping("/**/{path:[^\\.]*}", headers = "X-Requested-With!=XMLHttpRequest")
  fun forward(): String? {
      return "forward:/"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather go solution where I configure a `WebMvcConfigurer` instead. Please see below for code.

**Maven Configuration**

Maven configuration directs `frontend-maven-plugin` to build angular and copy built content into `target/static` directory, so that it is available in final WAR and JAR built. Then I additionally configure a `WebMvcConfigurer` to find a resource in static directory of JAR / WAR, if found - send it to client, otherwise redirect to index.html.

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-clean-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>*.js</include>
                <include>*.txt</include>
                <include>*.html</include>
                <include>*.css</include>
                <include>*.map</include>
                <include>*.json</include>
                <include>*.ico</include>
                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
              </includes>
            </fileset>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/assets</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**</include>
                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
              </includes>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>auto-clean</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/static</outputDirectory>
              <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/main/${angular.project.name}/dist/${angular.project.name}</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <workingDirectory>src/main/${angular.project.name}</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <nodeVersion>v14.16.1</nodeVersion>
            </configuration>

          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>npm build angular</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>run build:prod</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

**MVC Configuration**

Here you try to find if a resource exists in your static directory, if not redirect it to index.html.

You may have to change source location as per your requirement.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationWebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
              @Override
              protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location)
                  throws IOException {

                Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                if (requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable()) {
                  return requestedResource;
                }

                return new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");

              }
            });

  }

}
```

You should add extra Controller for corner case for path / or ""

```
@Controller
public class StaticContentController {

    private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    public StaticContentController(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Resource serveStaticContent() {
        // Load and return your static HTML file
        return resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/static/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is not exactly equivalent to the solution with the earlier AntPathMatcher, but it is still the one that does replicate the previous behaviour the most.

The biggest difference is that we do not get any JSON 404 errors when making requests through the Frontend with the X-Requested-With header. It's not a big deal, but still worth considering.

Comment: Hey. May I know what other functionality you want here ? Perhaps there could be an alternate way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, with this angular routes works as it should be

Answer (score 1):

PathPatternParser equivalent to previous AntPathMatcher `/**` would be:

```java
@GetMapping("/{*path}")
```

according to spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html):

> /resources/{*path} — matches all files underneath the /resources/, as well as /resources, and captures their relative path in a variable named "path"; /resources/image.png will match with "path" → "/image.png", and /resources/css/spring.css will match with "path" → "/css/spring.css"

Edit - relating to loop:

in your case in order to avoid the loop due to the use of `forward:/` if you only care about loading your angular page just replace `forward` with the actual content of your index.html

if for some reason you need to forward in order to flatten the uri before returning the response you can solve it in various manners
you can either `forward:/index.html` @GetMapping("/index.html") which should have precedence over wildcard or use `@PathVariable` in order to differentiate behavior and avoid eternal forward loop

```java
@Controller
class SpaRoutingController {

  @GetMapping("/{*path}")
  fun forward(@PathVariable(value="path", required=false) path: String): String? {
      if ("/".equals(path)) { // may need to handle additional cases
         return ""; // or your index.html
      }
      return "forward:/";
  }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this, and it does not work as you have described, because the forwarded request matches the same controller and results in a StackOverflowError. If you know how to break the cycle, please update the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

While using **Angular** you can not talk about pages such as `index.html`. What you have it to a route !

So when you redirect, you should do is to a **route** not a page.

```
ModelAndView forward() {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
```

PS : If `/` is your default route.

Comment: note that `redirect:` will return 302 response to the client with `Location` header for the browser to redirect to, while `forward:` occurs entirely on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Servlet Filter to handle endpoints not handled by Spring Boot? This article from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-exclude-filter) explains a solution which you could check for your use case.