# Two requests with same map

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to get user information by ID and by Username. Can I have 2 requests like this?

```
 @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
public User getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return userRepository.getOne(id);
}

@GetMapping("/user/{username}")
public User getUser(@PathVariable String username) {
    return userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
}


public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long>{

@Query("SELECT u FROM u WHERE username= :#{username}")
User findUserByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

Error: `findUserByUsername(java.lang.String) but parameter 'Optional[username]' not found in annotated query 'SELECT u FROM u WHERE username= :#{username}'!`

Comment: Not sure to understand what is missing.

Comment: i mean. how does it know if it's an id or a username. Can I do this?

Comment: instead of using 2 different end points  use same endpoint and return based on the condition weather it is Id / username

Comment: btw if any of the answers helped you, you could accept that answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5):

If I remember correctly you can do that via a regex like:

```
@GetMapping("/user/{id:[\\d]+}")
@GetMapping("/user/{username:^[a-fA-F]{100}$}")
```

Comment: Didn't know about that, it looks like you are right , cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527321/what-is-the-meaning-of-id-in-a-spring-mvc-requestmapping-handler-method

Comment: @Berger I *vaguely*  remember this to be honest, had to do it quite a lot of time ago

Answer (score 2):

No, You can't do that as both requests can be mapped to both the methods.
A Better way to do it would be to,

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public User getUser(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("userId") Long userId) {
   // find by Criteria.
}
```

And Call it like,

`http://<host>:<port>/<context>/user?userId=123&username=abc`, the query params atre optional and so you can omit whatever isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a text based protocol so the path parameter is always a string.

You should solve that with @RequestParam.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with request parameter:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/user", params = "id")
public User getUser(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
    return userRepository.getOne(id);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/user", params = "username")
public User getUser(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
    return userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
}
```