# Spring RESTful URL call passing parameters

Tags: spring, rest, uri

How do I make a URL call to the following method if the testId is **1211.ml:FA890987422**. Since there is a ':' in the testId, I try to make a request using URLEncoding (%3A for :) like this

```
http://localhost:8080/test/1211.ml%3AFA890987422
```

When I use the above URL, I get testId as **1211** as opposed to **1211.ml:FA890987422** even though '.' does not require URL encoding. What am I doing wrong?  Also, would there be any other way to pass this testId to this method if I want to skip URL encoding?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{testId}",
   method = RequestMethod.GET,
   produces = "application/xml")
public @ResponseBody String testResource(
    @PathVariable String testId){

    System.out.println("Test Id: "+ testId)
    // other codes follow
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate question [Spring MVC @PathVariable getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated) .

Try using regular expression in the request map and it should let you grab the entire string.

Comment: Thanks, I searched but could not get the exact match, may be my search string was not appropriate