# Controller Pathvariable bind removes ending space

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was wondering why Spring `@PathVariable` in the Controller is removing the spaces at the end of a word. for example my ajax is sending `XYZ123`. When this message is bind to a String with `@PathVariable` the ending space is removed by Spring. While it is send to the server as the correct String with the space.

The **URL** is send to the controller like

```
http://mydomain.com/user/XYZ123%20
```

and still spring is removing the space.

Is this just a bug, or is there a reason for it?

Comment: Can you please check [another post][1] talking this URL problems.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated

Answer (score 0):

That is probably due to the fact the additional trailing whitespace means nothing to a URL. In other word, both "http://mydomain.com/user/XYZ123" and "http://mydomain.com/user/XYZ123 " convey the same meaning.

If you want the space to persist, try [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)-it, eg:

http://mydomain.com/user/XYZ123%20

Comment: Hello Gerrytan thanks for you answer, but that is just the thing the url is encoded like 'http://mydomain.com/user/XYZ123%20' and still spring is binding it without the trailing space. I have updated my question with your input. Thanks