# Get request only works with trailing slash (spring REST annotations)

Tags: java, spring, rest, annotations, trailing-slash

I have a Spring REST Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/myresource")
public class MyResourceController {
  ...
}
```

With a GET request method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/{value1}/{value2}/{value3}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE + ";charset=UTF-8")    
public ResponseEntity<MyResponseType> getMyResource(
  @ApiParam(value = "...",...)
  @PathVariable("value1") String value1,
  @ApiParam(value = "...",...)
  @PathVariable("value2") String value2,
  @ApiParam(value = "...",...)
  @PathVariable("value3") String value3) {
//...
}
```

I would expect this method to be callable with:

```
http://myserver:8080/myresource/value1/value2/value3
```

But it is only reachable with a trailing slash:

```
http://myserver:8080/myresource/value1/value2/value3/
```

Why is that so or what is causing this?

Swagger assumes there are no trailing slashes and I can't send a request with swagger now.

What can I do to only make the first URL work but not the second?

Thanks a lot in advance for your comments and answers.

---

Edited 2:

I found out that without the slash the information of value3 is incomplete. value3 must be an email address but everything from the final dot is cut off.
So instead of "myemail@something.de" I am getting "myemail@something".

This explains why I can't get a proper result (no content and HTTP status code 404).  But I still don't understand why this happens. Further than that, if I have an email address with three letters in the top level domain (like .com) the request never reaches the GET method "getMyResource" ....

---

Edited 1:
My web.xml looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">
<display-name>(my) Services</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Provide ServletContext -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>my.ServletContextUtils</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Expose request to current thread (required for session and request-scoping) -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/config/spring-mvc-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And my spring-mvc-servlet.xml looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:env="http://my/schema"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
    http://my/schema
    http://my/schema/env-0.3.xsd">

<env:initialization />
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<context:component-scan base-package="my.myresource.restapi" />

<context:property-placeholder
    ignore-unresolvable="true"
    location="
        WEB-INF/config/${my.environment}/webapp.properties" />

<!-- Swagger -->

<!-- swagger config -->
<bean class="my.restapi.swagger.SwaggerConfig"/>
```

webapp.properties does not contain much:

```
swagger.include-pattern=/(?!api-docs|version).*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[Spring MVC @PathVariable getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated)

This seems to happen only with the last parameter and the solution is to use a regex for the last value:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/{value1}/{value2}/{value3:.+}"
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have a lot of applications using Spring Rest annotations and my APIs works with or without the trailing slashes.

It may be a problem with your Spring MVC configuration or with the http server you are using.

Could you post some code snippets with you Spring MVC configurations. It would be good to known which Spring version you are using and how are you serving the webapp.

Edit 1:

As I read in your second edit you are having problems with email parameters right?

Can you try using something like that and let me known if it resolves the issue?

`@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/{value1}/{value2}/{value3:.+}"...`

The problem seems to be with the dot in the url.

Reference: [Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Comment: Thanks for your question. I just added my configuration.  I don't have problems with the POST requests, though. Swagger posts them correctly and receives responses.

Comment: Oh yes, did not see your edit, yes I found this myself now, too. It does work indeed!

Answer (score 1):

in your web.xml file

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

what if you try without * just / (as shown blow), what result have you got?

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Comment: @pathvariable with email address is like known issue.
that you can have a look here.
[link  .. 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated)

and here
[link  .. 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)