# Spring Boot @RequestParam truncating URL's passed in with ?'s and #'s

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've seen a similar issue to this when using Spring MVC @PathValue but none of the solutions online for that worked for this issue.

I am currently working on an app where users will enter a URL and @RequestParam seems to truncate the URL's passed in on ?'s and #'s.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/route/path", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public Value method(@RequestParam(value="url") String url, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    //execute code
```

Now for example if someone were to pass in localhost:8080/route/path?url=https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/#article-header-id-0
the query would be truncated to url=https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

The same thing seems to happen with '&' as well.  I've tried a myriad of solutions around regexes, Bean configuration, and overriding configurePathMatch in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

Has anyone else had this issue?  If so, did you find a work around?  Thanks in adavance!

Comment: have you tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated

Comment: or perhaps its because you are using Chromes Rest Console to test

Comment: Because that is how URLs are supposed to work. Everything after `#` is for the client only a anchor. If you want it passed to the server you would need to url-encode it. Trying to solve it on the server side isn't going to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) to encode your parameter `url`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Percent Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) on the incoming url.

`#` is `%23`

`?` is `%3F`