# Spring: Could not resolve view with name when url contain dot and correct extension

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download/{product}/{topic}/{key:.*}")
//@ResponseBody
public AjaxResult download(@PathVariable("product") String product, @PathVariable("topic") String topic,
    @PathVariable("key") String key, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

Since the `key` path variable may contains dot, so regular expression is used, and class `AjaxResult` extends `LinkedHashMap` and all getter and setter are added, so it can return json result. the view resolver is as follow:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="viewResolvers">
          <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
        </list>      
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and the converter:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
        <bean id="fastJsonHttpMessageConverter"
            class="com.alibaba.fastjson.support.spring.FastJsonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
                    <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                    <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="features">
                <array>
                    <!--<value>WriteMapNullValue</value> -->
                    <value>QuoteFieldNames</value>
                    <value>DisableCircularReferenceDetect</value>
                </array>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter"
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
            <constructor-arg value="UTF-8" index="0" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

and `<mvc:annotation-driven />` `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` are added.

The problem is when i access like: `/download/product/topic/key.abc`, it works fine, but when access: `/download/product/topic/key.txt`, error happens:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/download/product/topic/key' in servlet with name ''
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.render(TestDispatcherServlet.java:105)
```

Please notice the difference between the two url, in a word when access a url that contains **a dot and a correct file extension**, error happens.

You may see that i comment the annotation `@ResponseBody` of the controller, if a add `@ResponseBody` and access url `/download/product/topic/key.txt`, error happens:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:137)
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Update

1. add trailing slash as said in [Spring MVC @PathVariable getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated) can solve my problem, that is :

@RequestMapping(value = "/download/{product}/{topic}/{key:.*}/")

and when access using `/download/product/topic/key.txt/`, but is there any other solution that won't change the value in `@RequestMapping` and url?

Answer (score 0):

add below conde into `.xml`
 file of your Spring Configuration:

```
<context:annotation-config/> 
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
<property name="messageConverters">
  <list>
    <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
  </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

you can try to add `DispatcherServlet` into your `web.xml` file, you can find code below:

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, still the error javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/download/product/topic/key' when access url '/download/product/topic/key.txt'

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem as follow:
for in my spring servlet config xml, there is a bean `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`, so i add a bean `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean` and set it property `favorPathExtension` to `false`, so below is my config file:

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false"/>
    <property name="favorParameter" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">    
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="contentNegotiationManager"/>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
          <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And you don't need `@ResponseBody` in your controller